# how to remove part of text/paragraph from column in the MySQL table, that start and end with some specific words?

Tags: mysql, text, paragraph

I need MySQL query to remove part of text/paragraph from MySQL column that start and end with some specific words.

Example : this is my column value

> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It
> has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making
> it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
> Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure
> Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going
> through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
> undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and
> 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the
> theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line
> of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in
> section 1.10.32.
>
> The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced
> below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de
> Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their
> exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914
> translation by H. Rackham.

**from this i want to remove few line of text that start with "The standard chunk of Lorem" and end with "translation by H. Rackham"**

Basically to remove the last paragraph from the column. Need MySQL query only, no need other option, because i have more than 4000 post, which i can't remove the text manually.
Kindly let me know MySQL query to solve the above issue.

Comment: See SUBSTRING_INDEX()

Comment: can you show some example using SUBSTRING_INDEX() how to solve my issue?